# How to calculate this limit at $1$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

What is the limit of   $$\lim_{r\to1}\int_{S\setminus V}\frac{d\sigma(\xi)}{|r\eta-\xi|}$$ where $S$ is the unit circle  of $\Bbb{R^2}$, $\eta\in S$ and $V$ is an neighbourhood of $\eta$ in $S$.

Thank you a lot of.

Comment: Can you define $\sigma$?

Comment: Ok. $\sigma$ is the Lebesgue measure on the circle $S$.